# Delete session cookies qt

Tags: c++, qt, session, cookies, qnetworkaccessmanager

I have a qt application where I am storing all the session cookies in `cookieJar`. In order to delete the session even without closing the application, I am currently calling `cookieJar->deleteLater();` when a button is pressed.

This is throwing the following error:
`The inferior stopped because it triggered an exception. Stopped in thread 0 by: Exception at 0x54d6559d, code: 0xc0000005: write access violation at: 0x1, flags=0x0 (first chance)`

The `cookieJar` is currently a public variable and it was initialized with the current class as the parent. Why am I still unable to delete it?

Comment: Maybe try to pass empty list in `QNetworkCookieJar::setAllCookies()` instead of delete. this exeption looks like you use bad pointer(non existing pointer)

Comment: @Chernobyl : I tried this earlier (`QList<QNetworkCookie> cookieList = new QList<QNetworkCookie>();
    cookieJar->setAllCookies(&cookieList);`) but this does not work. Mind showing me how to pass an empty QList?

Comment: new? You don't use pointer, maybe try this: `QList<QNetworkCookie> cookieList(); cookieJar->setAllCookies(cookieList)`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to destroy the QNetworkCookieJar, because:

```
Note: QNetworkAccessManager takes ownership of the cookieJar object.
```

Deleting of QNetworkCookieJar instance will cause accessing bad pointer by QNetworkAccessManager.

You can implement following to delete all cookies entries:

```
foreach (QNetworkCookie& cookie, networkAccessManager->cookieKar()->allCookies())
{
    networkAccessManager->cookieKar()->deleteCookie(cookie);
}
```

Comment: Okay. Then how exactly can I clear all cookies so that I can successfully delete my session and logout?

Comment: NETWORK_ACCESS_MANAGER->cookieJar()->setAllCookies(QList());  should works good

Comment: Just implemented it, now it is throwing this error: `QNetworkCookieJar::setAllCookies cannot access protected member declared in class 'QNetworkCookieJar'`

Comment: You are right, it's protected, I will update answer ... you can instantiate new QNetworkCookieJar to replace old, or get list of all cookies first and then delete one by one them.

Comment: allCookies is protected too.  You evidently didn't try this out.  Is a cookieKar perhaps a circus cookie in the shape of a clown car?

Answer (score 0):

To do this for the general case, you're probably gonna have to subclass it, so you can access allCookies() or setAllCookies().

I wound up with this mess, to clear them after a network request:

```
void YahooCookieTest::replyReady(QNetworkReply *reply)
{
    QList<QNetworkCookie> cookies =
      reply->header(QNetworkRequest::SetCookieHeader).value< QList<QNetworkCookie> >();

    // read cookies if desired

    foreach (const QNetworkCookie &c, cookies)
        namNetAccessManager.cookieJar()->deleteCookie(c);

    // etc. ...
```

These cookiejar structures are especially hard to work with.  You aren't allowed to get the value() of a header without a template cast.  There's no method to empty the cookie jar for you.  You can't even get at all the cookies in the cookie jar, without subclassing it.  You can set cookies with a QString, but you can't access them as QStrings.  I like Qt very well; but I feel this particular corner of it is bad API design.  To prevent unnecessary subclassing, it seems to me, *all ya gotta do, is make fewer things protected!*

I've tried this only on the case of a single cookie.  I think it'll work on more; but I'm making no promises.